# Не удается подключить CSS к HTML Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, css

Не удается подключить CSS к HTML

код в index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>text</h1>
        <b class="txt">text</b>
    </body>
</html>
```

Код в style.css:

```
.body { background-color:rgb(33, 182, 182);
```

Comment: во-первых покажите файловую систему, если у вас все в одной папке то сделайте ```./style.css```

Comment: @AndreyFreiz, сайт - не линукс, `./` писать необязательно.

Comment: @Qwertiy так как тут ОС не указана да и код новичка, вероятнее всего у него Windows

Comment: @AndreyFreiz, html-страница обрабатывается браузером по стандарту html. Точка ничего не меняет. И ОС не имеет значения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в CSS задан класс body, а не тег. Уберите точку перед body в CSS, а затем почитайте про азы каскадных стилей.